# Unity3D detecting a 2D joint break?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have realized that `OnJointBreak(float force)` is only for 3D physics.

Is there any way to detect a joint break in 2D physics?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, however, there is a

> OnJointBreak2D(Joint2D brokenJoint)

be aware that it is not in the documentations and that it takes a parameter of Joint2D